# Esbuild: Node module CSS are not including in the bundle

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bundle, esbuild

I am trying to create a library using EsBuild. I am using the keen slider in my library and I am importing keen-slider/keen-slider.min.css in main ts file.

```
import "keen-slider/keen-slider.min.css"
```

but in the output css file, keen slider css is not present. instead "import "keen-slider/keen-slider.min.css"" line itself present in output js file.

Can anyone tell me how to import node module css in the bundle?

Comment: Can you provide a code example or a link to the repository?

Answer (score 2):

Not the exact same CSS I was trying to load, but using the esbuild-sass-plugin worked for me. Don't let the name fool you, it will work perfectly fine with regular CSS files. I tried various other plugins that looked like they would work, but each failed.

```
const esbuild = require("esbuild");
const {sassPlugin} = require("esbuild-sass-plugin");

esbuild.build({
    entryPoints: ["app.jsx"],
    bundle: true,
    watch: true,
    outfile: "app.js",
    plugins: [
        sassPlugin({type: "style"}),
    ],
});
```

Comment: I cannot believe I was missing {type: "style"} -_-

Answer (score 1):

ESbuild does not support CSS imports. You can use esbuild-plugin-css-modules.

Step 1:

```
yarn add --dev esbuild-plugin-css-modules
or
npm install --save-dev esbuild-plugin-css-modules
```

Step 2:
Change your build script

```
const { build } = require('esbuild');
const cssModulesPlugin = require('esbuild-plugin-css-modules');

build({
  entryPoints: ['src/index.ts'],
  bundle: true,
  outfile: 'dist/bundle.js',
  plugins: [cssModulesPlugin()]
}).catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

Step 3:
Import the css file.

```
import "./path/to/keen-slider.min.css";
```

Comment: Can you try the same example with importing from node_modules? Like in question `import "keen-slider/keen-slider.min.css"`

Answer (score 0):

[in esbuld css docs](https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#css)

> import from JavaScript You can also import CSS from JavaScript. When
> you do this, esbuild will gather all CSS files referenced from a given
> entry point and bundle it into a sibling CSS output file next to the
> JavaScript output file for that JavaScript entry point. So if esbuild
> generates app.js it would also generate app.css containing all CSS
> files referenced by app.js. Here's an example of importing a CSS file
> from JavaScript:
>
> ```
> import './button.css'
>
> export let Button = ({ text }) =>
>   <div className="button">{text}</div>
> ```

this should work by default. But if you have an issue with this, you could use [On-load callbacks](https://esbuild.github.io/plugins/#on-resolve-results). docs show the example for `txt` files. BUt if you work with `css`  there will be quotes and '' will be conflicting. so we would have invalid javascript. so we need to escape `` from the data.

```
let exampleOnLoadPlugin = {
  name: 'example',
  setup(build) {
    // Load ".txt" files and return an array of words
    build.onLoad({ filter: /.css$/ }, async (args) => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(args.path);
      const escapedData = data
          .replace(/\n/g, "") // first replace will collapse css into one single line. new lines are removed
          .replace(/"/g, '\\"') // this will escape all ""
          .replace(/'/g, "\\'"); // this will escape all ''

      // you could inject the css to the document
      //  const contents = `
          const style = document.createElement('style');
          style.innerText = '${escapedData}';
          document.head.appendChild(style);
      //  `;
    })
    // or you may need to return like this
    return {
        contents: JSON.stringify(escapedData),
        loader: 'css',
  }
  },
}
```

you need to register this plugin

```
await esbuild.build({
  entryPoints: ['app.js'],
  bundle: true,
  outfile: 'out.js',
  plugins: [exampleOnLoadPlugin],
})
```

Comment: This problem is specific to imports from node_modules. I know how to configure it for `import './button.css'` but the same configuration not work for `import 'npm-library/button.css'`

Comment: r u trying to output the `css` file. if you are on the browser, you cannot access to file system. so you have to fetch it and inject it into the `DOM`